# How to avoid freezing browser upon generating lots of html elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using [Selection.js](https://simonwep.github.io/selection/) to create a selectable grid on my web page. In order for this to work, it needs to have x amount of divs that create the selectable area.

In my case, I create all the divs with a for loop, to then return it as an array

```
renderBoxes() {
        let boxArr = [];
        this.boxSize = this.state.wrapperWidth / this.props.columns;
        let length = this.props.columns * this.props.rows;
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            boxArr.push(<Box key={i}/>)
        }
        document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].style.setProperty('width', this.boxSize + "px", null);
        document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].style.setProperty('height', this.boxSize + "px", null);
        this.boxesCreated = true;
        return boxArr;
    }
```

When I set the column count to 100 and row count to 100, it takes quite some time to load.

So my question is: how can i generate lots of divs with the least amount of load time?

Render function:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-9 position-relative" id="box-wrapper">
                <div className="background-wrapper">
                    <img src="img/design.jpg" alt=""/>
                </div>
                <section className="box-wrap green m-0">
                    <div className="boxes red">
                        {this.state.wrapperWidth ? this.renderBoxes() : ""}
                    </div>
                    <div className="handle py-2">
                        Drag to increase/decrease vertical box count
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Is this using React?

Comment: Yes, I am using React

Comment: well i guess its not with your renderBoxes() function, its rather the actual view update/draw process or the way you instanciate the selectionjs, where is the code where the boxes are inserted to the dom, is renderBoxes maybe called multiple times?

Comment: I've updated my question and added the render function. It's only being called once. I guess you're right on the view update/draw process being slow. Is there any way to eliminate this? Maybe render x amount of divs at a time?

Comment: the only thing can help you while having 10k cells is virtual scroll or some similar component that keeps only visible elements in DOM

Comment: @skyboyer do you have a link that i could use as reference?

Comment: Manipulating the DOM with document.styleSheets is a huge mess when it comes to react and virtual DOM, it's better to do it the react way  and benefits the virtual DOM use the style attribute in the component.

Comment: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Comment: hm, I've checked generating 100×100 table and it happens actually in less than 1 sec with plain JS(`createElement`/`appendChild`). but it hangs up for 5+ seconds if I try to generate 500×500. so maybe it makes sense to figure out maximum expected value and make profiling to find out bottle neck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, thanks to @skyboyer. Creating the elements with `document.createElement` speeds up the process of rendering 100x100 divs by an insane amount.